Cambios automaticos en visual studio Community
Estoy teniendo un problema en mi proyecto ( en Visual studio Community), al compilar sin modificar una linea de codigo, me arroja que tengo varios cambios pendientes. Basicamente necesito omitir estos cambios que realiza de manera automatica, ya que, tengo el .gitIgnore. Estos son algunos de los cambios pendientes que me arroja git :
   modified:   FinanzApp/Business/bin/Debug/net6.0/Domain.dll
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/bin/Debug/net6.0/Domain.pdb
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/bin/Debug/net6.0/Infrastructure.dll
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/bin/Debug/net6.0/Infrastructure.pdb
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/Business.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/Debug/net6.0/Business.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/Debug/net6.0/Business.assets.cache
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/Debug/net6.0/Business.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/Debug/net6.0/Business.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/project.assets.json
    modified:   FinanzApp/Business/obj/project.nuget.cache
    modified:   FinanzApp/Domain/bin/Debug/net6.0/Domain.dll
    modified:   FinanzApp/Domain/bin/Debug/net6.0/Domain.pdb
    modified:   FinanzApp/Domain/obj/Debug/net6.0/Domain.AssemblyInfo.cs
    modified:   FinanzApp/Domain/obj/Debug/net6.0/Domain.AssemblyInfoInputs.cache
    modified:   FinanzApp/Domain/obj/Debug/net6.0/Domain.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que tiene que ver compilar con git???

Normalmente las carpetas bin y obj  deben quitarse del trackeo de git, agregándolas al .gitignore, el tema es que parece que ya las agregaste a tu proyecto por lo que por mas que las ignores, git va a seguir controlándolas. Lo que puedes hacer es eliminar las carpetas, hacer un commit y luego agregar las carpetas al .gitignore
